# What is wrong with functions.php? Fills error log with same error

Tags: functions, wp-admin, errors

After a third-party developer was used to reconnect our calendar with the Google Calendar API 3, we found that our .../wp_admin/error_log infinitely wrote:

```
[14-Apr-2015 11:46:59 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /home/USERFOLDER/public_html/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/functions.php on line 2410
```

We have disabled writing to the error log, as it literally repeats that error until the HDD fills. In the functions.php file, line 2410 referenced in the error above is blank; the code around it is as follows:

```
function THEMENAME_sort_terms_hierarchicaly($cats, Array &$into, $parentId = 0, $level = 0){

    foreach ($cats as $i => $cat) {

        if ($cat->parent == $parentId) {

            $into[$cat->term_id] = $cat;

            $into[$cat->term_id]->level = $level;

            unset($cats[$i]);

        }

    }
 ///THIS IS LINE 2410
    $level++;

    foreach ($into as $topCat) {

        $topCat->children = array();

        THEMENAME_sort_terms_hierarchicaly($cats, $topCat->children, $topCat->term_id, $level);

    }

    return $into;

}
```

**Howdy_McGee** points out below that *in_array()* is not within the code snippet, I am reviewing the *6 in_array(...)* instances from the functions.php page but have not yet found the issue.

These first two are likely more precedent as they fall within the //Admin Section of the functions.php code.

```
// Adding is login page function

function is_login_page() {

    return in_array($GLOBALS['pagenow'], array('wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php'));

}
```

Other in_array(..) from admin section:

```
// Remove unwanted items from admin menu

function THEMENAME_remove_admin_menu_items() {

    $remove_menu_items = array(__('Dashboard'),__('Posts'),__('Media'),__('Pages'),__('Comments'),__('Appearance'),__('Plugins'),__('Users'),__('Tools'),__('Settings'),);

    global $menu;

    end ($menu);

    while (prev($menu)){

        $item = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);

        if(in_array($item[0] != NULL?$item[0]:"" , $remove_menu_items)){

        unset($menu[key($menu)]);}

    }

}
```

Is there something here that I have missed that would reference line 2410 and cause this error? Do I need to rewrite each of my...

```
in_array(x,$y)
```

with... ?

```
is_array($y) && in_array(x,$y)
```

Comment: There is not an `in_array()` in the code you posted. Search your file for `in_array()` calls and every instance add a conditional to verify what is given is `! empty()`

Comment: Thanks again for a good starting point, I have found two in_array()s within the Admin portion of our function.php's code.

Comment: Just post line `2410` of your `functions.php` - neither of those snippets should be the cause of the problem, because in both cases argument 2 is always an array.

Comment: Hi there, it's the blank line with the comment from the first snippet: 
    }
 ///THIS IS LINE 2410
    $level++;

Answer (score 0):

In case you use a "child theme", i would search also in the parent themes function.php

@see https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: It seems I missed some in_arrays(...) in my original search, but I still have not been able to link them to the error or line 2410.

Comment: if you have a function call in line 2410, have a look into that function code also. sometimes, php ain't able to backtrace an error correctly (but that's very seldom)

Comment: This is a bit of a last resort, but have you tried wiping the error file and restarting Apache (or Nginx & php-fpm)? Just to make sure it is logging as you'd expect.

Comment: We did restart modules/apache and wiped the log file, server continued to report same error. So we disabled writing to log file as it would fill HDD and make everything unresponsive.